# DIV vertical alignment on mobile screen sizes

Tags: html, css, mobile, alignment

I'm currently in the process of overhauling my website on mobile. I've been running into problems configuring the clickable DIV boxes on my front page for mobile screens. Here is a link to my site: https://www.thefloodplains.com/

I want those same clickable DIV boxes to appear when viewing the front page of my mobile site - but with the caveat that I only want two of them to fill the space of the mobile screen (one in the top half, and one in the bottom half of the screen).

Here is what the front page of my site on mobile currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom DIV does not makes it all the way down the page. I want the two DIVs to have the same area, with one occupying the top half of the mobile screen, and the other, the bottom.

Ultimately, I want the mobile landing page to look more like this:

[image]

Here is the CSS/HTML for the front page:

As you can see, I am using ".col-md-5" specifically for mobile. I have tried a variety of methods, including changing the height to 50% (as shown above), but this seems to only get the top half height to 50% on mobile.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* min-height: 850px; */
  max-width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-repeat: repeat-x; */
  background: white;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background: url(OceanWater.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond", 'EB Garamond';
}

h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond", 'EB Garamond';
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background-image: url('AboutIcon.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  background-image: url('ArticlesIcon.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div3 {
  background-image: url('CodingBrackets2.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div4 {
  background-image: url('ContactIcon.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div5 {
  background-image: url('FSMusicArt.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div6 {
  background-image: url('AudioProduction4.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div7 {
  background-image: url('Violin3.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div8 {
  background-image: url('GalleryImage2.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#div9 {
  background-image: url('Handshake2.png');
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

div {
  background-image: url(../images/please-dont-use-spaces.jpg); //add the background image
  background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
  background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
}


/* @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .mobileShow {display: inline;}
            .mobileHide {display: none;}
        }    */

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .desktop-only {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .desktop-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .mobile-hide {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-hide {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Buenard|EB+Garamond|Lora|Roboto';

/* Original
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

.col-md-5 {
  color: #0081A5;
  height: 50%;
}

.col-md-5:hover {
  background-color: #FFE097;
}

.col-md-5 h3 {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.col-md-4 {
  color: #0081A5;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #F97B62;
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-4:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}

.col-md-4:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.col-md-4 h3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.col-md-4 h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/* The Hover Effects */

.col-md-4 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.col-md-4::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.col-md-4:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  z-index: 99999;
}

.col-md-4:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Button */

.btn {
  background: #F97B62;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F97B62, #0081A5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F97B62, #0081A5);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F97B62, #0081A5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F97B62, #0081A5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F97B62, #0081A5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 60;
  -moz-border-radius: 60;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: solid #666666 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #666666 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #FFE097;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFE097, #FFE097);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFE097, #FFE097);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFE097, #FFE097);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFE097, #FFE097);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFE097, #FFE097);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Basic Structure
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond", 'EB Garamond';
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="desktop-only container">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="About.html" title="About the site and Author">
        <div class="col-md-4" id='div1'>
          <h3>About</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Articles.html" title="Articles and Original Content">
        <div class="col-md-4" id='div2'>
          <h3>Articles</h3>
        </div>
        <a href="CodingCorner" title="Code and Resources for a Variety of Projects">
          <div class="col-md-4" id="div3">
            <h3>Coding Corner</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="contact.html" title="Contact The Floodplains & The FloodShark">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div4">
          <h3>Contact & Social</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="thefloodshark" title="The FloodShark Music and Media">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div5">
          <h1>
            The FloodShark Music
          </h1>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="FloodplainProductions.html" title="An enigmatic, virtual record label">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div6">
          <h1>Floodplain Productions</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="ClassicalCorner" title="A nook dedicated to sharing and categorizing classical music">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div7">
          <h3>Classical Corner</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Gallery.html" title="Images, Photographs, and Album Art">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div8">
          <h3>Gallery</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="support" title="Contribute to The Floodplains">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="div9">
          <h3>Contribute / Support</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-only desktop-hide container">
    <div class="mobile-only desktop-hide row">
      <a href="thefloodshark.html" title="About the site and Author">
        <div class="col-md-4" id='div1'>
          <h3>The FloodShark Music</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-only desktop-hide row">
      <a href="FloodplainProductions.html" title="A nook dedicated to sharing and categorizing classical music">
        <div class="col-md-5" id="div7">
          <h3>The Floodplains</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's what my site looks like on Desktop, for reference:

[image]

Absolutely any and all help would be deeply appreciated. I am fairly certain my problem lies with my CSS and my current use of @media.